# in PHPCR-ODM, filter Document by a value contained in an ArrayCollection?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, jcr

for a project at work, we are using PHPCR-ODM. we have a Document with the following field:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 * @PHPCRODM\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="SystemSize")
 */
private $system_sizes;
```

we'd like to provide the user a list of checkboxes - one for each possible SystemSize - and then search for any document that contains *at least one* of the SystemSizes specified.

for example, suppose object A has Small and Large, object B has Medium and Large, and object C has Large. a user selects Small and Medium. we should find objects A and B.

one of my co-workers suggested creating an additional field that represents a list of all of the referenced documents - so in this case, a text field called system_sizes_list - and then use a LIKE comparison to search against that field.

given the number of limitations we've run into with PHPCR-ODM, it's possible this the best solution... but I really don't want to believe it; surely there's a better way! I just can't find it >_>

possibly-relevant: PHPCR-ODM does not (currently?) support `leftJoin()`, `in()`, or `orX()->addMultiple()` (although you can simulate `orX()->addMultiple()` using `call_user_func_array()`...)